# Windows NFC login

Tags: windows

I have a motorola RFID enabled phone. I would like to scan the card for a sector with a certain password, then be able to log me into my Windows computer. How to do that?

I have tried a bluetooth keyboard emulator, also a wifi bluetooth emulator, but none of those has worked. I am looking for something that will start running before the user is logged in, I have seen facial recognition and such run before the user is logged in. I am just looking for some way for my phone to send a signal when a RFID card is put in front of it with the right data, and log me into my Windows computer.

Comment: I tried to fix your question, but it is still far from acceptability. What have you tried?

Comment: Just said in the post what I have tried!

Comment: Wonderful, now you have a much better chance to useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to write some software for your phone that would act as a NFC<->Network proxy and finally a credential provider for your Windows machine that would talk to the card (through the phone) and log you in if the credentials are correct.

It would take way too much time and effort to create this, let alone make sure it's secure (I wouldn't recommend writing security-related stuff unless you're a very experienced programmer - don't roll your own crypto).

However from existing commercial solutions you may take a look at [Aloaha Smart Login](http://www.aloaha.com/smartcard-software-en/aloaha-smart-login.htm) which is a credential provider for many types of smartcards, both contacted (credit cards/PKI cards) and contactless (Mifare Classic).

Note: if you plan on using this I suggest you take a Mifare Plus instead of the old and vulnerable Mifare Classic. Plus cards are backwards-compatible with Classic ones but fix their known vulnerabilities.

Comment: I will look into Aloaha Smart Login!

Comment: What if, I used a rfid arduino shield, would that work better?